# How to get the return value of the first parameter _StartAddress of function _beginthread

Tags: c, multithreading, return, beginthread

I wanted to do something using multi-threading and all the stuff encapsulated in function `foo` .

```
filterThread = _beginthread (foo, 0,NULL) ;
```

and I wanted to let `foo` return value:

```
int foo()
{
    return iRet;
}
```

but the prototype  of _beginthread `_CRTIMP uintptr_t __cdecl _beginthread (_In_ void (__cdecl * _StartAddress) (void *),
        _In_ unsigned _StackSize, _In_opt_ void * _ArgList)` shows that `foo` must be void which means cannot return value .
Is there any way else i can do to let `foo` return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the return value aka exit code of thread:

Call [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function on thread's handle after it has finished,

```
DWORD ExitCode;
GetExitCodeThread(hThread, &ExitCode);
```

As an example, consider using _beginthreadex instead,

```
unsigned __stdcall foo( void* pArguments )
{
    _endthreadex( 0 );
    return 0;
} 

int main()
{ 
    HANDLE hThread;
    unsigned threadID;

    hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, foo, NULL, 0, &threadID );

    WaitForSingleObject( hThread, INFINITE );

    CloseHandle( hThread );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`_beginthreadex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) instead.This allows you to use a function that returns a value. You can then use [`GetExitCodeThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683190%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get the value when the thread completes.